# Why is this UIButton still triggering event hander while disabled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, uibutton

I have a UIButton in a view. I attach an Event handler to it like this:

```
[self.button addTarget:self  
           action:@selector(button_touchUpInside:)      
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The handler looks like this:

```
-(void) button_touchUpInside:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", ((UIButton *)sender).enabled ? @"ENABLED" : @"DISABLED"); // Logs DISABLED
   // Do stuff
}
```

I disable the button like this:

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    enabled_ = enabled;
    self.button.enabled = enabled;
}
```

My problem is that even after I set `enabled = NO` on the button a `TouchUpInside` still triggers the handler. I can see in the handler that the button is disabled, however the handler is still triggered.

Please note that there are several ways of working around this - checking for button.enabled in the handler, @sanchitsingh's answer below etc. WHat I want to know is why this is happening.

Comment: Where you are setting enabled = NO?

Comment: Your NSLog statement is incorrect.  It should be like below:
NSLog(@"%@", ((UIButton *)sender).enabled ? @"ENABLED" : @"DISABLED");

Comment: @Apruv Sorry. Bad copy/paste. Fixed now.

Comment: Did you associate button_touchUpInside: with any other UI item's action?

Comment: @Nuzhat Zari Added it, but the fact that I can see the button is disabled in the handler shows that the button was definitely set correctly to be disabled.

Comment: My question was where you are setting it to NO, can you please post the entire code where you are creating button?

Comment: And you calling -(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled?Or may be you are calling -(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled and sending YES as parameter somewhere in the code.

Comment: @NuzhatZari Yes. It's called from the UIViewController much earlier in response to a model changing.

Comment: My suggestion is just put NSLog inside -(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled and print latest parameter value passed YES/NO.

Comment: @NuzhatZari I've done this already. Button is disabled a single time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my personal experience, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326051/how-can-a-disabled-button-get-touches), and others thread across the web, it seems that Apple's documentation about [UIControl.enabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) is incorrect, and that setting a UIControl disabled doesn't prevent it from getting touch events. It only neutralizes a few events such as (from memory, can't check now) click, touch down, and current action-triggering 
events, so you effectively have to use UserInteractionEnabled property to really get rid of touch events.

Comment: But Apple don't make mistakes ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just check if there is any gesture involved in your code. That could cause a problem.
I think you should just use

```
 button.enabled = NO;
 button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: There are no Gesture Recognisers used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
button.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to work around this, but I'm trying to understand what might be causing it.